# Defining skipper in separate translation unit using Boost.Spirit X3

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

How to define skipper grammar in separate translation unit?
What is the type of output attribute should be? Or can I simply specify `boost::spirit::x3::unused_type` as `Attribute` template parameter to `boost::spirit::x3::rule` template class for skipper grammar? I think the skipper grammar should only internally move forward input iterator over blanks, newlines, comments, etc. It is better in sense of performance and memory allocations/frees. How to define a context type for such grammar, which should I provide to `BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE` macro?

Comment: I guess this is a sign I should start looking at Spirit X3 :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

`using skipper_parser = x3::rule< class skipper_class, x3::unused_type const >;` is the definition of skipper parser type (`const`-ness of returned type is important thing).

`BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE(skipper_parser, iterator_type, x3::unused_type)` is the instantiation of `parse_rule` template function for the skipper somewere in separate translation unit.